# White screen with stripes after startup

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

Today I turned on my computer, everything was going fine, POST displayed with no problems, but when windows 10 loaded this was shown on display:
[image: windows 10 after startup]

First thing I checked, since I have multiple systems on my computer I tried to start windows xp, on a system selection screen these artifacts were displayed:
[image: system selection screen]

However windows xp run with no problems.

So I tried booting into recovery mode in windows 10, again, everything was fine.
First thought: uninstall graphics drivers.

I did that, restarted computer, and the drivers were back there again, like nothing happened.

Another thing that grabbed my attention was this error(Standard display different than PnP)
[image: Standard display different than PnP]

Another random thought: chkdsk, found errors, running with /f, restart, everything seems fine, logging in, black screen, hard reset, artifacts are back!

Starting recovery mode again, scanning disk again, found different errors, restarting with /f, however this time the problem with artifacts has evolved: [image: even more artifacts]

It might seem as graphic card problem. However the problem does not persist on other OS nor does it in recovery mode. The constant disk error might indicate that there is the problem.

My graphic card: Radeon R9 270, which has only HDMI and DVI ports, I am using an adapter VGA -> DVI
It worked before with no trouble, happened after my brother hard reset computer while playing game

Could it be disk error or it is sure that it's graphic card failure?

## EDIT:

so I used AMD driver removal tool, and managed to start windows 10 without recovery mode, scanned HDD.

Neither SMART nor surface test shown no errors.

I thought that it might have been just a temporary failure so I decided to install driver again, during the installation the screen went black and stayed until I hard reset the computer. The artifacts aren't back, but I cannot manage to finish the install of the driver.

Any other ideas?

## EDIT2:

Seems I have been wrong since the beginning. After running 'LCD Test Images' on computer, gradients page shows problems for both Windows XP and Windows 10. I also checked that on my HDMI TV, the stripes were still here. Seems that's a graphics card problem
[image: weird color stripes]

Comment: There's definitely an issue with the Windows 10 installation as it works fine on other OSs.  Next time you run scandisk, run it again, and again until it stops finding errors.  Sometimes it will see the errors and do nothing for some reason, and running it multiple times in a row without rebooting will get it to power through the error.  I've had to do that a few times in the past to get errors fixed.  BACKUP anything you value off of that drive though, this could be the first sign of a bigger issue.

Comment: In recovery mode some advanced features are disabled. It still can be an hardware problem. Check the HDD in recovery mode with the SMART report (I expect to find under Windows error to be corrected when you turn off with such kind of problems). When you are sure that it is not the Disk, reinstall all the graphic drivers (force a reinstall). Modify the graphic setting and restore them, to be sure to save the setting in a different file. Check for your monitor too (to exclude that the problem came from it), and how it is seen by your system. Disable all accelerations then enable one at once...

Comment: Please take a look at my updated post